# Merge/Combine two pdf using windows console

Tags: windows, pdf, command-line, merge

I'm searching for a Method to combine two (or more) PDFs to a new one. This i have to do with the comman-line in windows. I haven't found a simple programm that can do this.

Has anyone an idea for a programm that can do this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

I would install [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) under [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), then do something like the following (I always have to try the commands a couple of times to get them right):

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=out.pdf file1.pdf file2.pdf [...]
```

Comment: You've still a small error here and didn't get it right: it must be `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite`. Also, I would add `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` for maximal quality.

Comment: ghostscript is also available in native windows binaries, you don't have to use cygwin (see [here](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)).